# babel parameters french and frenchb cause compile error

Tags: babel

```
 \documentclass{minimal}
%\usepackage[french,english]{babel}  %ERRORs
%\usepackage[frenchb,english]{babel}  %ERRORs
\usepackage[english]{babel}
%===================              END PREAMBLE                =============
\begin{document}
Using either french or frenchb as babel parameters produce compilation errors:
!Undefined control sequence - abbreviations, disallowuchyph, overfullhboxmark, 
tabbingaccents, automaticlettrine.

Having worked with the parameter set [greek,russian,ngerman,frenchb,spanish,italian,
portuguese,english] in babel for a number of years without any issues whatsoever, 
this comes unexpected. 

What brought it on? I wished to experiment with the minted package, loaded it under 
my MiKTeX2.9 distribution, then abandoned again as it appeared that minted also 
required python-pygments and a Linux distribution rather than my MiKTeX/Windows. 
The end result is the error described above, which persists even after deleting 
minted from MiKTeX.

Totally puzzled!

\end{document}
```

Comment: This code compile fine for me, except one warning about `OT1 encoding`

Comment: @touhami something mysterious happened in my MiKTeX configuration when I loaded the `minted` package

Comment: You probably updated the format or some other package and now the versions no longer match. Show your log-file and check for update as user and admin (http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/108490/2388)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Your hint is the fix to the problem. Breaking the rules of the latex stack exchange: thank you! P.S. how do I flag your input as being the answer?